# Puzzle about the fourth parameter of "ScrollWindow" API function in Windows Programming

Tags: c, windows, winapi

My code is shown below. When the program is running, I click the right mouse button first, then I click the left mouse button. The result is shown as in the first picture. According to the help document of `ScrollWindow` function, if the fourth parameter is `NULL`, the entire client area should be scrolled. Why is there a 10 pixels gap at x = 30 device units?

[image: Actual result]

I'm wondering why the result is not shown like the second picture.

[image: Expected result]

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{

    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("HelloWin") ;
    HWND         hwnd ;
    MSG          msg ;
    WNDCLASS     wndclass ;

    wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0 ;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0 ;
    wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance ;
    wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION) ;
    wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH) ;
    wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL ;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName ;

    if (!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("This program requires Windows NT!"), 
                    szAppName, MB_ICONERROR) ;
        return 0 ;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName,                  // window class name
                         TEXT ("The Hello Program"), // window caption
                         WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        // window style
                         CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial x position
                         CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial y position
                         CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial x size
                         CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial y size
                         NULL,                       // parent window handle
                         NULL,                       // window menu handle
                         hInstance,                  // program instance handle
                         NULL) ;                     // creation parameters

    ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow) ;
    UpdateWindow (hwnd) ;

    while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
        DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
    }
    return msg.wParam ;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC         hdc ;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
    RECT rect;

    switch (message)
    {          
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
            EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
            return 0 ;

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            SetRect(&rect, 30, 0, 70, 100);
            ScrollWindow(hwnd, 10, 0, NULL, &rect);
            UpdateWindow(hwnd);
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
            return 0;

        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
            hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            Ellipse(hdc, 0, 0, 100, 100);
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
            return 0;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0) ;
            return 0 ;
    }
    return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

Comment: Please give more details on your input. You click a button, i.e. you press down on it, do not move it while down and then release it? Then the other button the same?

Comment: You are not painting in `WM_PAINT`, so it's normal that you get garbage on screen. The specific kind of garbage you get is not particularly interesting.

Comment: This is the common case of broken painting code.  The right-click just splatters pixels onto the window, they are not going to survive for very long.  Most easily seen by dragging the window partially off the screen or minimizing and restoring it.  And visible in the screenshot, ScrollWindow can't move pixels outside of the clip rectangle and the subsequent paint it generates doesn't draw them either.

Answer (score 1):

> if the fourth parameter is NULL, the entire client area should be scrolled.

You also specify a clipping rectangle (the 5th parameter), so of course not the entire client area will be scrolled. But actually that's not relevant for the problem.

> Why is there a 10 pixels gap at x = 30 device units?

Because you don't paint that gap when Windows tells you to do so.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787591(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The area uncovered by ScrollWindow is not repainted, but it is combined into the window's update region. The application eventually receives a WM_PAINT message notifying it that the region must be repainted.

Your `WM_PAINT` handler does ... nothing except lying to Windows by validating the update region.

Fix your code by doing all the painting only in `WM_PAINT`. When you scroll in `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` you will also have to increment a variable that stores the scroll position. Add the scroll position to the coordinates you pass to `Ellipse()` in `WM_PAINT`. Now you should get a result like the 2nd picture.

I suggest to find a good tutorial on Win32 painting in general as some basic knowledge seems to be missing here. Get an understanding about what the "update region" is and how it interacts with the paint cycle.

Comment: According to your answer, I still have two questions.

Comment: @user7028 What questions?

Comment: According to your answer, I still have two questions. 1. As the fourth parameter doesn't take effect. What's the necessity of the existence of the fourth parameter? 2. You said "From MSDN:

The area uncovered by ScrollWindow is not repainted, but it is combined into the window's update region. The application eventually receives a WM_PAINT message notifying it that the region must be repainted." I wondered whether "the area uncovered by ScrollWindow" is the area uncovered by the fourth parameter or the fifth parameter?